# Dates between today and another date

Tags: date, haskell, monads

im burning my brains trying to make a function that gives me the ammount of days between todays date and a given date.

possible **today** function:

```
today = fmap (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d") getCurrentTime
```

and thought using `diffDays`, but wont be able to make it work with a **::Day** date

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `formatTime` version returns a string, but you want a `Day` (which looks like your string when you inspect it, but is a different type entirely). Here's one way to write a `today` function, using `utctDay` to get a `Day` out of a `UTCTime`:

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Clock

today :: IO Day
today = fmap utctDay getCurrentTime
```

And here's a days-from-today function (which I gave the shorter name `daysAway`) that uses it:

```
daysAway :: Day -> IO Integer
daysAway day = fmap (diffDays day) today
```

If you're always specifying the target as a calendar date, you can do that easily enough:

```
daysToDate :: Integer -> Int -> Int -> IO Integer
daysToDate year month day = daysAway $ fromGregorian year month day
```

Given a shorthand function for a commonly-needed relative day:

```
tomorrow :: IO Day
tomorrow = fmap (addDays 1) today
```

We can demonstrate the correctness of Annie's Thesis:

```
ghci> tomorrow >>= daysAway
1
```